# Modulus of "set"-continuity for Wiener Field

Tags: reference-request, pr.probability, stochastic-calculus

My question concerns some "set-wise" continuity properties of Gaussian random fields, more specifically of Wiener fields (see definition here: https://encyclopediaofmath.org/wiki/Wiener_field).

Let $W$ be a ($d$-fold) Wiener field over $[0,1]^{d}$. Let $A\subset [0,1]^{d}$ be a Borel set. We define
$$W(A)=\int_{A}dW.$$
I wonder if we have some Lévy's modulus of continuity "set-wise" analog here? More precisely, for $L(A)$ the Lebesgue measure of $A$, is there a modulus of continuity $\omega$ such that, almost surely,
$$\sup\limits_{A\subset [0,1]^{d},\text{ Borel set}}\frac{|W(A)|}{\omega(L(A))}<+\infty$$
My feeling is that we can take $\omega(r)=\sqrt{r\log(1+1/r)}$ as it already holds for that $\omega$ if we only consider sets of the form $[0,t_{1}]\times...\times[0,t_{d}]$ (as proved in: https://projecteuclid.org/journals/bernoulli/volume-21/issue-2/Exact-moduli-of-continuity-for-operator-scaling-Gaussian-random-fields/10.3150/13-BEJ593.full).

Maybe this does not hold for all Borel sets; in this case, I would be curious what restrictions we have to impose on sets. Do there exist published results in this direction?

Edit: I think this can be shown as a consequence of corollary 1.3 (second case) from https://projecteuclid.org/journals/annals-of-probability/volume-14/issue-2/Sample-Moduli-for-Set-Indexed-Gaussian-Processes/10.1214/aop/1176992533.full

Comment: The bound for all Borel sets fails already for $d=1$ since Brownian motion has infinite variation. The reference you mention requires the class of sets to be quite 'small' in some sense.

Comment: @MartinHairer Thank you. I haven't edited the question since, but I had figured out that wanting this property for all Borel Sets was silly. Still, (but maybe I have misunderstood the article of Alexander) we can have control over the continuity modulus of the Wiener field on all hypercube of $[0,1]^{d}$ (or more generally balls for a given norm). As I mentioned in my question, I am curious of what class of sets we can consider and what kind we can't.

Comment: To be clearer : If we only consider not too wild classes of sets, for example open sets with a unique connected component, it's not so clear for me why it does not work

Comment: That's still way too wild: when $d=2$, take sets of the form $A\times [0,1]$ and then connect them with a very thin strip to essentially reduce yourself to the case $d=1$ with arbitrary open sets. Hypercubes are of course fine.